# Allow SSRS report users to enter parameters and filter results. Two options, "Yes" and NULL. Unable to include in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to run a report where there are 7 parameters, each pertaining to a column in a SQL Server DB. The values in those columns are either "Yes" or NULL. In my WHERE statement, I'm comparing the value of the parameter with the value of the queried columns but it seems as if it doesn't work when it's NULL. The columns are NVARCHAR(25). I specified two available values in the report, one value is "Yes" and the other is (null) *** this is how it shows up when you select null value in SSRS.

How do I structure my WHERE statement to compare to a string of text or NULL?

```
SELECT
  Contact.EmailAddress
  ,Campaign.CampaignName
  ,Event._ContactId
  ,Contact.IMS
  ,Contact.ADV
  ,Contact.INS
  ,Contact.PWM
  ,Contact.AMD
  ,Contact.CRP
  ,Contact.PB
FROM
  Event
  INNER JOIN Contact
    ON Event._ContactId = Contact._ContactId
  INNER JOIN Campaign
    ON Event.CampaignId = Campaign.CampaignId
WHERE
  Contact.EmailDomain != N'seic.com'
  AND Contact.IMS = @IMS
  AND Contact.ADV = @ADV
  AND Contact.INS = @INS
  AND Contact.PWM = @PWM
  AND Contact.AMD = @AMD
  AND Contact.PB = @PB
  AND Contact.CRP = @CRP
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just add an IS NOT NULL check to see if the parameter was NULL to each of your conditions.

```
AND (Contact.IMS = @IMS AND @IMS IS NOT NULL)
```

This way it will meet the criteria if the Contact = your parameter value (YES) or the parameter is NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This doesn't seem to work. It still returns all results no matter if the column contains 'Yes' or it's NULL. I want to filter on those parameters based of what the variable @IMS is set as.

Comment: Duh - sorry. It should have been not null. I'm thinking now that your column can be NULL too - not just Y/N.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that NULL can't be compared to NULL with an equals operator.

This is probably the shortest way to write a solution, though it might not be the most performant:

```
AND ISNULL(Contact.IMS,'') = ISNULL(@IMS,'')
AND ISNULL(Contact.ADV,'') = ISNULL(@ADV,'')
...
```

While it's longer to type and read, this might actually perform faster, since it avoids functions in the WHERE clause:

```
AND (Contact.IMS=@IMS OR (Contact.IMS IS NULL AND @IMS IS NULL))
AND (Contact.ADV=@ADV OR (Contact.ADV IS NULL AND @ADV IS NULL))
...
```

The BEST solution, in my opinion, even though it's the most work, would be to change those columns to Non-nullable bit-type columns, with a default value of 0.  And your report parameters could only be 1 or 0:  not NULL.   Then you could use the simple equals operator you were using in your original query.

But if you're not able to make that change for some reason, the first two solutions I gave above will be your best bets.